# OpenSSL: How NOT to include Subject/Authority Key Identifier?

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I've seen X.509 certificates that do not have Subject/Authority Key Identifier embedded. For testing purpose, I would like to create similar ones as well. I tried to modify OpenSSL conf file like below.

```
subjectKeyIdentifier    = no
```

or

```
subjectKeyIdentifier    = none
```

But obviously it doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

More attempts: empty, null, ''. But none works, even removing this line.

Comment: OK, I got it. I should change the conf of signer.

Comment: Good find. You should probably add your comment as an answer, and then accept your own answer. Its not gratuitous - it helps others find questions *and* answers (and not just questions).

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).